# ernst vs ernst zu nehmen

Tags: difference

I have heard/read the following sentence in [DW news](https://www.dw.com/de/02102020-langsam-gesprochene-nachrichten/a-55130218):

> Der Gebrauch einer chemischen Waffe stelle einen ernst zu nehmenden Bruch internationalen Rechts dar

Is there any difference in meaning between "ernst zu nehmend" and "ernst" ? The former seems just a wordier form of expressing the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be argued that there's a difference between a serious breach and a breach that has to be taken seriously. The former suggests an objective fact (i.e. that the breach was indeed serious, perhaps according to some well-defined standard); the latter suggests that in the circumstances the breach, no matter its objective status, has to be taken seriously. However, in the context of chemical weapons, I can't imagine an instance in which their use would ever be one but not the other, i.e. their use would always be serious **and** have to be taken seriously. (By contrast, an event at a nuclear power facility might not be serious according to the International Nuclear Event Scale, but would arguably have to be taken seriously no matter its allocation on that scale.) Given the quote you provide is reported speech, it's also possible this remark was made in response to an actual or perceived indifference amongst colleagues or relevant parties (e.g. states, IGOs) to the use of chemical weapons. In short: It's hard to say, but it is possible the speaker isn't just being wordy but is capturing a relevant nuance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this even has anything to do with the German language. There's a small semantic difference between the two that you can probably express in every language.

"einen ensten Bruch" just gives the speaker's assession of the "Bruch internationalen Rechts", while "erst zu nehmen" talks more about something that should be done by other persons or a group of persons, namely take it seriously and e.g. act on it as opposed to just letting it slip.

I don't know who is reported to say this here, but it's probably someone who isn't able to act alone, but at least needs the consent of others, which kind of is the norm in democratic institutions.

Comment: "Ernster Bruch" translates to "serious breach" whereas "ernst zu nehmender Bruch" translates to "breach that must be taken seriously" (see the other answer). So this small semantic difference can also be expressed in English and has indeed not much to do with German language.